# Parallel make build in kdevelop

Tags: makefile, kdevelop

How do you configure kdevelop to perform builds in parallel?

The command line equivalent might be:

```
make -j 4
```

...to run four jobs in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Project* -> *Open Configuration...*

Click on *Make* on the left. Then set the value you want under *Number of simulataneous jobs*.

[image]

These instructions apply to KDevelop 4.4.1, but may apply to earlier versions as well.